# Pandas group by : Include all rows even the ones with empty column values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am using Pandas and trying to test something to fully understand some functionalities.

I am grouping and aggregating my data after I load everything from a csv using the following code:

```
s = df.groupby(['ID','Site']).agg({'Start Date': 'min', 'End Date': 'max', 'Value': 'sum'})
print(s)
```

and it works with the following file:

[image]

but it does not work with this file:

[image]

For the second file, I am getting the data only for the 56311 ID. The reason is that some columns have empty values. But that should not matter. I have not found anything relevant about that. I have only found how to exclude the null columns.

Except for this issue, what are the main things that I should take into account before grouping? Is there any chance that rows will be excluded because for example of a format (date or number)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is problem if `NaN`s in columns in `by` parameter, then groups are removed.

So need replace `NaN` to some value not in `Site` column and after groupby replace back to `NaN`s:

Thanks `Zero` for simplifying solution with `fillna` in `groupby`:

```
df1= (df.groupby([df['ID'],df['Site'].fillna('tmp')])
        .agg({'Start Date': 'min', 'End Date': 'max', 'Value': 'sum'})
        .reset_index()
        .replace({'Site':{'tmp': np.nan}}))
```

If need `NaN`s in `MultiIndex`:

```
s = (df.groupby([df['ID'],df['Site'].fillna('tmp')])
       .agg({'Start Date': 'min', 'End Date': 'max', 'Value': 'sum'})
       .rename(index={'tmp':np.nan}))
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'Site':[np.nan,'a',np.nan,'b','b','a'],
                   'Start Date':pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=6),
                   'End Date':pd.date_range('2017-11-11', periods=6),
                   'Value':[7,3,6,9,2,1],
                   'ID':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A   End Date ID Site Start Date  Value
0  a 2017-11-11  a  NaN 2017-01-01      7
1  b 2017-11-12  a    a 2017-01-02      3
2  c 2017-11-13  a  NaN 2017-01-03      6
3  d 2017-11-14  b    b 2017-01-04      9
4  e 2017-11-15  b    b 2017-01-05      2
5  f 2017-11-16  b    a 2017-01-06      1
```

---

```
df1= (df.groupby([df['ID'],df['Site'].fillna('tmp')])
        .agg({'Start Date': 'min', 'End Date': 'max', 'Value': 'sum'})
        .reset_index()
        .replace({'Site':{'tmp': np.nan}}))

print (df1)
  ID Site   End Date Start Date  Value
0  a    a 2017-11-12 2017-01-02      3
1  a  NaN 2017-11-13 2017-01-01     13
2  b    a 2017-11-16 2017-01-06      1
3  b    b 2017-11-15 2017-01-04     11

s = (df.groupby([df['ID'],df['Site'].fillna('tmp')])
       .agg({'Start Date': 'min', 'End Date': 'max', 'Value': 'sum'})
       .rename(index={'tmp':np.nan}))

print (s)
          End Date Start Date  Value
ID Site                             
a  a    2017-11-12 2017-01-02      3
   NaN  2017-11-13 2017-01-01     13
b  a    2017-11-16 2017-01-06      1
   b    2017-11-15 2017-01-04     11
```

Comment: Instead of assign for single-liner you could `df.groupby(['ID', df['Site'].fillna('tmp')])...` perhaps?

Comment: @jezrael I posted a new interesting question where I am really stuck. If you have time :)

Comment: Do you think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46956837/2901002) ? I think is necessary doublr groupby, unfortunately

Answer (score 7):

In Pandas versions > 1.1.0, you can pass `dropna=False` to keep NaN values (see [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby)).

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: pd.__version__
Out[3]: '1.1.2'

In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [np.nan, 6]], columns=["A", "B"])

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
     A  B
0  1.0  2
1  3.0  4
2  NaN  6

In [6]: df.groupby("A").mean()
Out[6]: 
     B
A     
1.0  2
3.0  4

In [7]: df.groupby("A", dropna=False).mean()
Out[7]: 
     B
A     
1.0  2
3.0  4
NaN  6
```

Comment: what if my pandas is not that version